# Answers including sales pitch

Tags: discussion, spam

I'm currently reviewing answers in the Late Answers review queue and have happened upon the same user twice. Their answer to both questions ([Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573848/how-to-fool-distil-with-casperjs-phantomjs/54916859#54916859) and [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs/54917384#54917384)) was identical except for five words added to the beginning of Answer 1, and they both end with the user presenting a monetary solution.

I've been hesitant to flag them as spam because the answers do contain information about the questions. However, it is very generic information and does not give an example of how actually to implement the answer into the asker's solution.

I did end up flagging them due to Answer 2 already having other answers provided, but do others see these as legitimate answers or is it indeed a form of spam?

Edit: The [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22329212) in the queue was also the same.

Comment: They've been deleted so I guess you have your answer.

Comment: Two of them have a "closed as spam" banner while "Answer 1" is merely deleted, all by the same mod.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They are providing low quality answers while adding spam advertising to each post. It is actually both an answer as well as spam. This being said the spam section is sufficient for it to get blocked, marked as spam, or deleted. Indeed they have been either deleted or marked as spam.

Imagine if someone went around giving partially correct answers then attaching the same ad on each answer they provided. Something like this:

> Well actually Swift and Kotlin are so closely compatible that you there exists multiple code converters to switch the source code from one directly to the other. This also exists for Java and Kotlin as well as vice versa.
>
> I am selling cheeseburgers for 5$ a piece with 2 for one with the purchase of a combo.

If all of their answers have that last part in (The "I am selling cheeseburgers" part), even if they somewhat responded with an answer, they are still spamming ads.

Comment: Now I want a cheesburger.

Comment: ..two combos, two large fries and a coke with no ice, please! Can I pay with €?

Comment: Do you deliver?

Comment: It's a genius way to sell an answer, I'll say that. Put the idea of a cheeseburger in your head, pure happiness. That is an involuntary upvote waiting to happen.

Comment: –1 because I wanted a taco

Comment: I almost thought this was a real example